# How can setText without create new Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I can `setText()` of a label in the constructor of my `ConfirmDialog`, when I create a new object.
But I want to `setText()` when the component is `setVisible()`.

My program allows the user to choose between A or B. If they choose A, it opens a dialog and `setText("a")` on it, and if they choose B, it opens and `setText("b")`.
It should only create new `ConfirmDialog` once.

My **ConfirmDialog** class is

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public ConfirmDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        labelTitle.setText("Some text");  //labelTitle is jLabel
    }
...
}
```

When it creates new instance and sets `visible = true`

```
    ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
```

When I click button OK and close dialog

```
private void btnOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    this.setVisible(false);
}
```

If I open dialog again and want to change its text, like so

```
labelTitle.setText("another text");
```

without creating a `new ConfirmDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);`, can I just set it, or is there a method that allows `setText()`, when resuming on `setVisible(true)`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method that returns JLabel "labelTitle" in ConfirmDialog.

```
private getTitleLabel() {
    return labelTitle }
```

Using the already created instance of ConfirmDialog, u can change the text like this.

```
dialog.getTitleLabel().setText("your text"); //dialof is instance of ConfirmDialog
```

Comment: getTitleLabel() has private access in ConfirmDialog, I change to public method and work!! thanks for save my work. disadvantage if I change to public method?

Comment: No it should be public only. By mistake i mentioned private

Comment: this is suboptimal because the ConfirmDialog now exposes an implemenation detail - without need. For a better alternative, see [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15564891/203657)

Answer (score 2):

You sure can. Save a reference to the `ConfirmDialog` you create, e.g. as an attribute in your parent window's class.

`private ConfirmDialog dialog;`

Then add a setter-method to `ConfirmDialog` to set the label's text.

```
public void setLabelText(String text){
    labelTitle = text;
}
```

You can then use that set-method when you show the dialog.

`dialog.setLabelText("text");`

Comment: any different? if i use public JLabel getLabel() { ... }

and call dialog.getLabel().setText("text");

thanks

Comment: It'll do. Although if setting the text is the only thing you want, exposing the whole component might be overkill.